# Restart Dotnet Application After Crash

Tags: .net, server, cron, crash, auto

I have Ubuntu server 18.04. I have configured application (net core 2.1.806 app) which I run like this:
"setsid nohup dotnet Server.dll"

This application crashes sometimes,and i have to run above command to run service again. So is there any idea? if this app crashed, it goes automatically run "setsid nohup dotnet Server.dll" command and also inform me via mail. Thanks in Advance.